# trying to combine two separate excel sheets into one

Tags: python

```
 import xlwt
 import xlrd
 import os.path
 import os
 print os.path.abspath(os.curdir) 

#Create workbook and worksheet

wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wbk.add_sheet('Data_1')#name of the sheet in which new data is there

row = 0

f = xlrd.open_workbook('Data_1.xls')#workbook from where data is extracted
g = xlrd.open_workbook('Data_2.xls')#workbook from where data is extracted

sheet1 = f.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet2 = g.sheet_by_index(0)

for i in xrange(16):
temp = sheet1.row_values(i)
print temp
col = 0
for element in temp:        
    sheet.write(i,col,element)
    col += 1
i += 1

for j in xrange(16):
temp = sheet2.row_values(j)
print temp
col = 4
for elements in temp:
    sheet.write(j,col.element)
    col +=1
j+=1
 wbk.save('DATA.xls') #excel sheet name when saved in the folder
```

On executing i am able to get the data on my console for the Data_1.xls but the moment it   enters into second set of for loop it gives me error as follows:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python26/combining2ExcelSheets.py", line 34, in <module>
sheet.write(j,col.element)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'element'
```

One more thing the first column of my both the excel sheets(Data_1 and Data_2.xls) are same. If in my newly generated excel sheet I want to combine and organize my data according to the respective first column values. What should be my course of action so that desired sorted excel sheet is obtained?

Comment: `for elements in temp:
    sheet.write(j,col.element)
    col +=1` is what causing the error,  `col.element` should be `col,element`

Comment: In wbk.save when after merging I want to write merged data into file named as 'DATA.xls'; that file is not generated in the defined folder??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typo!

Replace:

```
sheet.write(j,col.element)
```

with

```
sheet.write(j,col,element)
```

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Comment: Makes sense. Voted to close. :)

Comment: FYI You keep your rep for posts with score +3 over 60 days old. Thanks very much!